# MySQL - order by distance from value giving priority to higher values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to order by distance from a value, giving priority to greater than or less than.  It might not be possible with a straightforward query, but I figured I'd inquire anyway.  Say I have a table named "scores":

```
Score
-----
24
27
23
29
```

I want to find the closest value to a score of 25, returning the closest value above 25 before looking below 25.

Attempting the following query will return `24, 23, 27, 29`:

```
SELECT score FROM scores ORDER BY ABS(score - 25);
```

Is there a straightforward way of saying **return the closest scores above 25 first, if none found, look down**?

I'm sure it's possible with subqueries, however my actual query is much more complex, with multiple joins and other criteria, so I'm worried about the overhead of using unions or subqueries (as well as the readability of the query).  Would like to find the simplest way of accomplishing this if possible.

**Edit:**

I want to ensure that I have found all scores above 25 before resorting to anything below 25.

Comment: You would have to provide more info on the logic. Is a score that is higher by 2 better than one that is lower by 1? Or higher by 3 better than lower by 1? etc. In other words, what is the scoring pattern that the result set should show?

Comment: @Jim.. See edit... I want to ensure that I have found all scores above 25 before resorting to anything below 25.

Comment: So a score of e.g. 300 should show up before a score of 24?

Comment: Yes.  Answers below were very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT score 
FROM scores 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN score > 25 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
  ABS(score - 25);
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b3c9/2)</kbd>

It gets the results as follows:

```
SCORE
27
29
24
23
```

Comment: Nice answer, very clean

Answer (score 1):

Try out:

```
SELECT score
FROM scores
order by (case when score > 25 then 0 else 1 end case), ABS(score - 25);
```